# What is the entropy of a random sequence of N elements in an interval containing S terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The NSA is always hunting down their next generation of employees. Since the entropy of a string of symbols chosen randomly from a set of N symbols is a measurable quantity, somebody must be able to wed physics with set theory and combinatorics permutations to obtain a spectral percent answer of the amount of chaos or order within a quantity of  information. The amount of energy required to restore order to a given piece of information is highly related to brute force algebraic attacks by computers operating at C cycles per second. If there is no algorithm that restores order, then the amount of energy required is the sum of every algebraic calculation to check every solution in the set of all solutions. Similar to the library of Babel and a reference system to check out only one book. How do you identify a single book out of all possible books without the same quantity of information contained in the book you desire to check out?

Comment: What is the energy of a car?

Comment: The entropy of such a string will be equal to the number of bits you have to know in order to exactly determine the string. Since your experiment is apparently based on equal probabilities for all outcomes, it will we a maximal value for that setting. The entropy in such a setting  will change only when your N symbols appear in different ratios/probabilities in your ballot box.